# How can I list the pods in a Kubernetes service?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubectl

My understanding is that a Kubernetes service identifies a set of pods.

I use `kubectl get pods -n <namespace>` to list the pods in a namespace and this works fine.

How can I list the pods in a specific Kubernetes service? I'd like to find every pod running in a service within a namespace.

Comment: your service will belong to a namespace and have a label selector in it. you can use the labels in your get pods command to get pods that only match those labels

Comment: @braebdeb Thank you That does answer my question